# Figuring out a syntax error on my first shell script

Tags: bash

I'm completely new to coding and this is my first script. I've been receiving this error from my code and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
| LAST NAME       | FIRST NAME | JOB    | OLD    | NEW    | MESSAGE                                 
: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
: line 25: `   else | '
```

The script is just supposed to read a text file. II've attempted to use gedit to see my mistake and all I've noticed is my JOB= line is discolored.

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "| % -15s | % -10s | % -6s | % -6s | % -6s | % -40s\n" "LAST NAME" "FIRST NAME" "JOB" "OLD" "NEW" "MESSAGE"

while read line
do

   USER ID=`               echo $line | cut -d '|' -f1 `
   LAST NAME=`             echo $line | cut -d '|' -f2 `
   FIRST NAME=`            echo $line | cut -d '|' -f3 `
   JOB=`                   echo $line | cut -d '|' -f4 `
   OLD NICE=`              echo $line | cut -d '|' -f5 `
   PREFERRED PASSWORD=`    echo $line | cut -d '|' -f6 `

   FULL NAME="$FIRST_NAME $LAST_NAME"

   if [ "$JOB" == "P" ]
   then
      NEW_NICE=3

   elif [ "$JOB" == "S" ]
    then
      NEW_NICE=6

   else | 
      NEW_ICE=7

   fi

   test -e /home/$USER_ID

   if [ "$?" == "0" ]

   then

     MESSAGE="$USER_ID already exists"

   else

     ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD=` echo "$PREFERRED_PASSWORD" | openssl passwd -1 -stdin `

     useradd -m -c "$FULL_NAME" -p $ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD $USER_ID

     mkdir "/home/$USER_ID/${LAST_NAME}_backup"

     chown -r $USER_ID "/home/$USER_ID/${LAST_NAME}_backup"

     echo "$USER_ID created"

  fi

printf "| % -15s | % -10s | % -6s | % -6s | % -6s | % -40s\n" "$LAST NAME" "$FIRST NAME" "$JOB" "$OLD" "$NEW" "$MESSAGE"

done < test3_data.txt
```

Comment: Why is there a "|" next to else?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  A few suggestions. (1) This isn't really about `vi`; the editor is immaterial.  It's a problem in the shell script. Consequently, the [tag:vi] tag isn't a particularly good choice. (2) It would be better to identify this as a shell problem, preferably identifying the specific shell ([tag:bash], to judge from the shebang line). (3) Given that you are using a modern shell (and not, say, an archaic Bourne shell on old Solaris), you would do better to use the `$(cmd …)` notation instead of enclosing commands in backticks.

Comment: You should probably use fewer blank lines, too.  Up to a point they increase readability, but too many of them make it harder to read the code; it's harder to see the paragraphs if every line is separated from the next by a blank line.  There's no need to go to the one-liner approach; there's a healthy balance in the middle.

Comment: Best practice is to check [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) which can help point out any syntax errors in your code